# Make custom tikzpicture section heading non-rigid

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, titles

Trying to make a custom section heading but I don't know how to make it move fluidly with the text, only by commanding it to be in a specific location on the page. I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is the code I have so far but it's meant to be implemented at the same spot every page:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[hmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=2.3cm,tmargin=2cm,centering]{geometry}
    \usepackage[contents= ,color=boxgray,scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0]{background}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{4cm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
    \textblockorigin{5mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner

    \definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{59,59,59}
    \definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{235,235,235}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usepackage{atbegshi}
    \tikzstyle{lw} = [line width=0.5pt]

    \newcommand\Header{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, fill]
            \path [fill=lightgray]
                ([yshift=9.8cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=9.8cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=9.3cm,xshift=12cm]current page.west) -- ([yshift=9.3cm]current page.west) -- cycle;
            \node[font=\bfseries\color{black},anchor=south west,
                  xshift=1cm,yshift=9.8cm] at (current page.west)
                  {\fontsize{40}{60}\selectfont\headertext};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }


    \pagestyle{empty}
    % add header depending on the value of the page modulo 3
    \AddEverypageHook{%
      \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
        \backgroundsetup{contents={\Header}}
      \else  
      \ifnum\value{page}=2\relax
        \backgroundsetup{contents={\Header}}
      \fi\fi
      \BgMaterial
    }

    \begin{document}

    \newcommand{\headertext}{Header 1}

    \begin{textblock}{4}(0.3,1.2)
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{textblock}


    \end{document}
```

I'm sure it's an easy fix but can't figure out how to make the tikzpicture move with the sections of the text. If possible, I'd like to get it out of the header environment as well as the header may be changing with the pages. This is just the easiest way I knew how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. In this case, you appear to missing part of the `\Header` macro...

Comment: Yes, my apologies. Code is updated above.

Comment: May be you should use `titlesec` and (re)define section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need this. (Ididn't understand the requirement properly though)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}   %% for demo
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
   {\fontsize{28}{32}\sffamily\bfseries}
   {}
   {-0.5cm}
   {\textcolor{blue!60!green}}
   [\vspace{-0.8ex}\hspace*{-1cm}\color{gray!60}\rule{0.5\textwidth}{2ex}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
   {0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
   {2.3ex plus .2ex minus .2ex}
%
\begin{document}
\section{Header 1}
\lipsum[4-5]
\section{Header 2}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh that does seem to work! How can I specify the font size by number instead of by \Large, as well as make the text bold. And how can I decrease the spacing between the text and the gray box? Couldn't figure out which number to change in the code. Thanks.

Comment: @TLC Please see the update. Change `\vspace{-0.8ex}` suitably.

Comment: that works brilliantly thanks! I came across another issue, however. If my title is longer than one line there's a HUGE gap between the two lines. Ideas on how to decrease this gap and make it normal?

Comment: @TLC May be it a candidate worth for a new question. Please add all details when you do. :-)